# How do you make a GUI from an exsisting textual menu using JOptionPane?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, joptionpane

I have created a class that has methods for getting, setting and displaying computer details. I have then created a test class that displays this methods and uses a textual menu for the user to interact with (shown below). I now need to upgrade this to a GUI interface using JOptionPane but I have no clue where to start as this is all new to me. If anyone has any advice or suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SystemTest_Y3881268 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create System_Y3881268 object and test methods
        System_Y3881268 s=new System_Y3881268("Lenovo", 
            "Ideacentre A340-24IWL", 2);
        s.setHardDisk(2);
        s.setMemory(128);
        s.setPurchaseCost(599);

        //Create textual menu
        int memorySize;
        double hardDiskSize;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice;
        do 
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("***** Computer system menu *****");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Choice 1: Print System Details");
            System.out.println("Choice 2: Diagnose System");
            System.out.println("Choice 3: Set Details");
            System.out.println("Choice 4: Print System Properties");
            System.out.println("Choice 5: Quit the Program");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 - 5");
            System.out.println();
            choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

            switch(choice) 
            {

            case '1': 
            {
                s.displayDetails();
            }
            break;

            case '2': 
            {
                s.diagnoseSystem();
            } 
            break;

            case '3': 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
                hardDiskSize = keyboard.nextDouble();
                if(hardDiskSize<2) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Hard disk size = Low");
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Hard disk size = Ok");
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter memory size in MB: ");
                memorySize = keyboard.nextInt();
                if(memorySize<128) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Memory Ok = False");
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Memory Ok = True");
                }

            }
            break;

            case '4' : 
            {
                System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();
            }
            break;

            case '5' : break;
            default :  System.out.println("Enter only numbers from 1 - 5");
                   System.out.println();
            }
        } while(choice != '5');
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you start by picking up a good book, or by reading a tutorial, like this one here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html ... meaning: your question is basically too broad. You are like: "ok, I know how to use a scooter, now can someone tell me in 1, 2 sentences how to ride the bike"?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have more flexibility than a JOptionPane I'd suggest you use the JDialog class. You can add components in the constructor of your dialog like JTextbox, JLabel, JButton and many more.
First, Create yourself a class that extends JDialog.

```
public class Whatever extends JDialog
{
    public Whatever(Frame ownerFrame)
    {
        super(ownerFrame, "Title", true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.rootPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(125, 0, 0), 3, true));
    }
}
```

Then in your main class your gonna call it like that :

```
Whatever whatev = new Whatever(myFrame);
whatev.setSize(800, 600);
whatev.setVisible(true);
```

For more info on the JDialog class : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Comment: Fun how ppl just downvote without any reason, this way nobody knows what their mistakes are and can't fix them.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this line of code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Message", "Title", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

where `f` is the parent `JFrame`, it can be `null`,
`JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE` is the type of the dialog.

For more information, refere to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: This is miles away from correctly answering the actual question...